# How can I programmatically open/close ngx cookie consent popup?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, cookieconsent

I'm using [ngx-cookie-consent](https://github.com/tinesoft/ngx-cookieconsent) with Angular.
I would like to find a way to programmatically display/hide the popup

I've tried accessing the method `close` through an instance of the `NgcCookieConsentService` without any success

the idea would be to have a link as so:

html:

```
<div>
    <span (click)="displayPopPup()"> display pop up</span>
</div>
```

.ts

```
displayPopup = () => {
    //trigger the popup display 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way I found was to call my the function `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` from the NgcCookieConsentService instance. thanks to [@Xperiencing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12806799/xperiencing) for making me look back at this problem

so in `.ts`

```
...
constructor(private ccService: NgcCookieConsentService){}
...
opencc(){
    this.ccService.fadeIn();
    //fadeOut to hide
}
```

then in htlm

```
<div (click)="opencc()">
    ...
</div
```

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor you can declare an instance of the NgcCookieConsentService class:

```
private ccService: NgcCookieConsentService
```

Then in your function you can call the open function to reopen the cookie popup.

```
this.ccService.open();
```

Comment: the problem with your answer is that when using `open` or `close` this initialize or completly close cookie consent  best is using `fadeIn`and `fadeOut`  for my purpose. Thanks anyway